# Categories Listing and Highlighting current category item

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks, posts

My query is on Wordpress and related to categories.

I have a set of categories for my posts: All, Cat-a, Cat-b and Cat-c.

a. When I click on the link to my posts page, I want to show an archive for 'All'. How do I generate a link to 'All' explicitly? Something of this kind?

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">All Posts</a>
```

b. I would also be displaying the list of categories (shown below). I would however need to highlight the current category (by default, All).

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

c. Also I would need all categories to be displayed whether they have posts in them or not.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

The styling suddenly worked out of the blue! :) Thank you so much!

However, a problem still remains. I have given the following arguments in the wp_list_categories function.

```
<?php wp_list_categories('show_option_all=All&hide_empty=0&title_li=&current_category=All'); ?>
```

I want the 'All' option to be visible in any category listing. However, since by default, all posts load, the styling for current_category should also apply to 'All'. However, since All does not have a category ID, I do not know how to apply the current-cat class to 'All'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

a)  Take a look at [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).  You will see "show_option_all" parameter, which will show an all categories option.

```
$args = array(    
'show_option_all'    => 'All Posts'
);
wp_list_categories($args)
```

b) I answered this in another question or yours.  Basically current-cat is by default on category archive pages, but if you want it on all pages, set current_category = 1 in the $args array above:

```
$args = array(    
'show_option_all'    => 'All Posts',
'current_category'   => 1
);
```

c) This is setting hide_empty to 0:

```
$args = array(    
'show_option_all'    => 'All Posts',
'current_category'   => 1,
'hide_empty'         => 0
);
```

Comment: I tried this approach - all it did was highlight the default category ('Uncategorised') as current, irrelevant of what page/category I was on.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue in my website's top nav. There are both Pages and Categories as well. I googled it and luckily got a solution that works for me.

```
.menu li.current_page_item  a { ... your css here for page items ... }

.menu li.current-menu-item a { ... your css here for category items ...}
```